# Scikit-neural_network has trouble with input data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network

I'm trying to train some neural network using [sknn](http://scikit-neuralnetwork.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html). I have preprocessed my data through a pandas dataframe. The preprocessing works fine when I use the fit(x_train,y_train) on standard sklearn classifiers, but it throws the attribute error

```
anaconda/envs/py3k/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2360, in __getattr__
(type(self).__name__, name))
 AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'todense'
```

or this error:

```
/anaconda/envs/py3k/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1750, in maybe_convert_indices
raise IndexError("indices are out-of-bounds")

IndexError: indices are out-of-bounds
```

Seemingly at random (different runs, without changing anything).

The relevant piece of code looks like this:

```
            x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(X_data, Y_data, test_size=1/kfold)
            regr = linear_model.LinearRegression(copy_X=True,fit_intercept=True)
            abr = AdaBoostRegressor(base_estimator=tree.DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=max_depth_gridsearch_values[max_depth_counter]), n_estimators = n_estimators_gridsearch_values[n_estimators_counter])
            nn=nn_simple_regressor


            x_train_numeric = x_train.iloc[:,2:]
            x_test_numeric = x_test.iloc[:,2:]

            regr.fit(x_train_numeric, y_train)
            abr.fit(x_train_numeric, y_train)
            nn.fit(x_train_numeric,y_train)
```

And the regressor is defined as

```
nn_simple_regressor = Regressor(
layers=[
    Layer("Rectifier", units=100),
    Layer("Linear")],
learning_rate=0.02,
n_iter=10)
```

I cannot understand why this is happening, and seems like the support for sknn is pretty small. I suspect the issue is actually with the preprocessing, but I don't understand why it works for the first two classifiers but not my NN. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of February 2016, Sknn does not support pandas. In order to fix the issues stated in the question, the best approach is to convert the dataframe into a numpy array. Using the .as_martix() function in pandas is the easiest way to do so.