# Error running sknn.mlp.Classifier

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn

I am trying to use sknn. The code relevant to this question is as follows:

```
import sknn.mlp as nn
alg = nn.Classifier(random_state=1, layers=[nn.Layer(type="Softmax", units=10)], n_iter=500)
alg.fit(data, labels)
```

where data and labels are imported from the classic mnist dataset. This works on any other sklearn model I tried, like LogisticRegression and RandomForestClassifiers, so I know the data is being imported correctly. However, when I run the Classifier from sknn.mlp, I get an error:

```
  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sknn/mlp.py", line 390, in fit
    return super(Classifier, self)._fit(X, yp, w)

  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sknn/mlp.py", line 232, in _fit
    self._train(X, y, w)

  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sknn/mlp.py", line 151, in _train
    avg_train_error = self._backend._train_impl(X, y, w)

  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sknn/backend/lasagne/mlp.py", line 305, in _train_impl
    return self._batch_impl(X, y, w, self.trainer, mode='train', output='.', shuffle=True)

  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sknn/backend/lasagne/mlp.py", line 286, in _batch_impl
    for Xb, yb, wb, _ in self._iterate_data(self.batch_size, X, y, w, shuffle):

  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sknn/backend/lasagne/mlp.py", line 275, in _iterate_data
    Xb, yb, wb = cast(X, excerpt), cast(y, excerpt), cast(w, excerpt)

  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sknn/backend/lasagne/mlp.py", line 261, in cast
    array = array[indices]

  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1986, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_array(key)

  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2031, in _getitem_array
    return self.take(indexer, axis=1, convert=True)

  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1628, in take
    convert=True, verify=True)

  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3637, in take
    indexer = maybe_convert_indices(indexer, n)

  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1810, in maybe_convert_indices
    raise IndexError("indices are out-of-bounds")

IndexError: indices are out-of-bounds
```

Anyone has any clue what this could come from?

Comment: Can you please show dimensions of data and labels?

Comment: print data.shape and print labels.shape give respectively (42000, 784)
(42000,). this is the mnist dataset, with 784 (28x28) pixels per image, one label (ranging from 0 to 9) and 42000 examples.

Comment: It looks like this is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35304681/scikit-neural-network-has-trouble-with-input-data  How do I deal with this, should I close the question?